# Nested redux state - getting an error "Cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying implement namespacing to components so that I can re-use the actions and reducers in different workflows. I have nested state structure. Here is how my root reducer looks

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
session: SessionReducer,
posts: PostsReducer,
form: formReducer,
employees : {
    currentPage : currentPageReducer('employees'),
    itemProperties : itemPropertiesReducer('employees'),
    items : items('employees'),
    itemsPerPage : perPageReducer('employees'),
    sortingProperty : sortReducer('employees'),
    filters : filtersReducer('employees')
}});
```

In the component, state is accessed like below

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {  
let myState = state[ownProps.namepspace];
return {
    currentPage: myState.currentPage,
    itemProperties: myState.itemProperties,
    items: myState.items,
    itemsPerPage: myState.itemsPerPage,
    sortingProperty: myState.sortingProperty,
    filters: myState.filters
};}
```

namespace is passed to the component as ownProps like below

```
<DataTable namespace='employees' />
```

Here is a sample action

```
export const REFRESH_FILTERS = 'REFRESH_FILTERS'; 
export function refreshFilters(namespace) { 
return { 
  type: `${namespace}/${REFRESH_FILTERS}`
};}
```

this is how my reducer looks

```
let filtersReducer = (namespace) => (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {      
    case `${namespace}/${REFRESH_FILTERS}`:
        return initialState;
    default:
        return state;
}
};
```

I am getting an error message in mapStateToProps function when I tried access the state saying "Cannot read property currentPage of undefined". Am i missing anything here? Is this not right way to access nested state properties?

Comment: I hope it's not just the spelling of namepspace, heh...

Comment: @brub - No, that was the first thing I checked ;-)

Comment: did you notice this? `let myState = state[ownProps.namepspace];`

Comment: @kishore Inside the mapStateToProps method, execute `console.log(Object.keys(state))` and show us the output

Comment: @brub - ahhh thanks. Couldn't catch that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot nest reducers like that. Either, you need to call them by yourself or use the combineReducers function to combine them. Try this as your root reducer,

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    session: SessionReducer,
    posts: PostsReducer,
    form: formReducer,
    employees : combineReducers({
         currentPage : currentPageReducer('employees'),
         itemProperties : itemPropertiesReducer('employees'),
         items : items('employees'),
         itemsPerPage : perPageReducer('employees'),
         sortingProperty : sortReducer('employees'),
         filters : filtersReducer('employees')
    })
});
```

**Edit**: Just to wrap things up, You had two issues in your code. One was the typo(Good catch by @brub), and the issue in combineReducers

Comment: Thanks. I changed it and still getting same error message.

Comment: @kishore That's weird. Did you correct the spelling mistake pointed out by @brub?